# Como remover um alias em bash?

Tags: bash, shell

No bash, como remover um alias?

Por exemplo, após fazer `alias man="man -a"`, quero apenas executar `man` ao invés de `man -a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para remover um alias:

```
unalias man
```

Para ignorar qualquer alias com o nome do comando, coloque `\` antes do comando:

```
\man
```